# Combine Sinkov score bigrams, trigrams and quadgrams

Tags: substitution-cipher, frequency-analysis

I am trying to break a special substitution cipher (where the text is divided into several columns and each column has its own substitution table). Currently I am trying hill-climbing.

For the score, I am using Sinkov, which I found at the [M4 project](http://distributedcomputinginfo.pbworks.com/w/page/17922396/M4).

The algorithm for the Sinkov score is like this ([My implementation in PHP](https://misc.daniel-marschall.de/crypto/dict/sinkov/sinkov_score.inc.phps)):

```
S = ln(f / u * e), u=MIN(f)
u is lowest non-zero frequency
f is frequency of that substring in sample text
e is base of natural logarithm.
```

I have created a lookup table for the Sinkov score for bigrams, trigrams and quadgrams, and I tested it with some good and bad text samples:

Sinkov bigram:

- Score of [good text](https://misc.daniel-marschall.de/crypto/dict/sinkov/test/good_text.txt): 106069
- Score of [bad text](https://misc.daniel-marschall.de/crypto/dict/sinkov/test/bad_text.txt): 83450

Sinkov trigram:

- Score of good text: 113648
- Score of bad text: 65496

Sinkov quadgram:

- Score of good text: 94478
- Score of bad text: 23528

Now my problem: I see that trigrams and quadgrams are very good to find out if a text is valid English or not. However, during the hill-climb process, both will show bad results, because it is unlikely that 'good' trigram/quadgrams are found on the first try.

So I am looking for a Sinkov score algorithm, which combines bigram, trigram and quadgram together, kinda like this:

```
Do a hill-climb to find 'good' bigrams.
Give 'bonus-points', if there are 'good' trigrams in it.
Give 'super-bonus-points' if there are 'good' quadgrams in it.
```

How can I achive this? And can I achieve this in a single score-function, or do I need to modify the hill-climb process (how?)